How do I call a Rascal function from Java
I am working on a Java CLI (using PicoCLI) to use along side my Rascal DSL by problem is this. How do I call a Rascal function (functions defined my DSL) in my Java CLI code? I have previously implemented this CLI in Python (using Click) and implemented the inter-ops between Rascal and Python using JPype but the performance was horrendous. I know how to call Java methods in Rascal but I would like someone to point me to an example on how to do the reverse because I would like to passing parameters and to the Rascal functions and get results back into Java.

Did you already look at the way they implement their REPL?
